# Crear grid xamarin personalizado

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Buenas Alguien me puede ayudar estoy desarrolando una aplicacion de prestamos y necesito crear una view tal como esta de la imagen [image: UNa Imagen como esta]

y algo asi tambien [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te dejo este artículo para que puedas entender mejor el funcionamiento del Grid. https://askxammy.com/working-with-gridlayout-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas, ambas páginas tienen la misma estructura:

- Barra de navegación con botones
- Lista de X columnas con cabecera y footer
- Botón de acción en la parte inferior

La página es un ContentPage, que contiene un Grid con 3 filas: header, lista y footer. La barra de navegación la implementas con un [NavigationPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/) que envuelva a tu ContentPage.

La lista la implementas con un ListView, algo similar a esto:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListaDatos}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- acá van las columnas -->
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

El resto es poner Buttons y los botones en el toolbar. Acá hay [una guía para el toolbar](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/).

Comment: Muchas gracias ivan con tu respuesta pude continuar con el proyecto